# Find lower-cased words enclosed by XHTML heading tags?

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm curious whether it's possible to get stand-alone REGEX to find words that begin with lower-case a-z contained within XHTML heading tags. I say "stand-alone" because I've already solved the workday problem with Python ala "find this, then do this". But I remain curious whether it's feasible to solve the problem with REGEX alone.

I don't believe this has anything to do with "parsing HTML / XHTML". I had about 30K lines of XHTML where every word after the first word in the headings began with a lower-case character. I needed to make them upper-case. I have access to REGEX dialects that support Replacement-String Case Conversion, I just needed to capture the instances.

Using [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) in *PCRE (PHP)* mode, `((\b[a-z])(\w+'?\w+\b))` is one way to capture the first character of all words that begin with lower-case a-z:

[image: REGEX finds words that begin with lower-case a-z]

**This came very close to doing what I need.** I already "get" that REGEX or even a programmatic solution's find/replace-with-upper-case won't produce a perfect solution. But it would quickly fix most of the worst problems.

It's even easier to use `(<(h[1-4]>))(.*)(<\/\2)` to find XHTML heading start/end tag pairs, then capture everything in between them as a single undifferentiated string:

[image: REGEX finds XHTML heading 1-4]

But it's finding the lower-cased words inside that undifferentiated string that I'm having trouble with. My two REGEX components as illustrated in the preceding screenshots always seem to prevent the other sub-expression's operation.

I'm guessing that there's a REGEX construct that would enable me to untangle this problem. I just can't find that construct...

**EDIT**: I would like to "thank" the "readers" who didn't actually bother to *read* the question but instead reflexively, unthinkingly saw *XHTML* and witlessly concluded it was about "parsing HTML" when it wasn't at all. As in, replace the incidental XHTML tags with, say, XXX. You evidently decided I was under-informed when you the down-voters were...

Comment: Obligatory don't parse html with regex. Other than that, you would probably have trouble finding something that wasn't a two part solution and I would be willing to say that even if you did find a solution, it would probably be less performant considering how regex engines work. Also, your regex example for finding everything within an h tag is overly verbose (too many groups that you don't need), You could make your regex nothing more than `<h\d>(.*?)<\/h\d>` which would be fine given the simple sample shown.

Comment: "Obligatory don't parse html with regex". Oh please. If instead of the heading tags the text had been surrounded by XXX or YYY, would that have been parsing HTML? Um, no. Please take a moment to consider a question before reflexively writing "don't parse HTML" just because a REGEX question includes a particular text construct of a particular form.

Comment: I doubt you can do that in PCRE efficiently. You might use something like [`(?:\G(?!\A)|<h\d+>)[^\w<]*\K\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/mPio8Q/1) or [`\b\p{Ll}\p{L}*\b(?=[^<]*<\/h\d+>)`](https://regex101.com/r/TyN99i/1) but these either require more programming logic around or are based on assumptions.

Comment: "I doubt you can do that in PCRE efficiently." That's sort of the gist of my question. Per my original question, I finally did this with some Python -- I'm mostly just curious whether REGEX alone would suffice...

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
[^<\/](\b[a-z])\w*\b
```

I capture a lower case letter preceded by a word boundary `\b` without a preceding `<` or `/` to exclude the `h` in the HTML tag, and succeeded by zero or more word characters `\w*` and a word boundary `\b`.

This picks up the short words (`is`, `a`) that your regex missed.

Comment: That does find the words. But as Wiktor Stribiżew observed in his comment, above, this may not be doable with PCRE alone.

Comment: Yeah I hear you. It will depend on the exact nature of the text and how quick and dirty you're comfortable with. I wouldn't use a regex like this to parse a HTML document, but if you just had a grep output or something .. maybe it would suffice.

Comment: I don't believe I'm using "regex like this to parse a HTML document...". HTML has nothing to do with it. Imagine that instead of the *text constructs* that happen to be HTML headers, the text I want to find/replace was surrounded by text strings XXX or YYY. So I might rephrase the question, "find lower-case words enclosed by specific text tokens" or the like. I think those who have downvoted my question did so because they didn't bother to actually think about the problem: they just saw the words REGEX and HTML on the same page and reacted in the Pavlovian sense with "parsing"...

Comment: HTML *in general* is too complex for a regex to parse but of course it is possible to parse a simple HTML document as long as it doesn't reach that level of complexity. It just depends. If your input is indeed as simple as your test cases then you'll be fine. If you're trying to parse arbitrary HTML documents then you will run into issues at some point and regex will not be sufficient.